# Read contacts with mail

Tags: android, filter, contacts

My code reads the phone contacts
I'm using "Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER" for the cursor.
My question is, as I can, if I can, filter to show only contacts with email?
Best regard

Answer (score 0):

You can filter contacts so that only ones with email show up, but there's no column you can filter on in Contacts.

Instead, you'll have to use Contacts.Entity and filter on MIMETYPE = CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.

I suggest you take a look at the javadoc for these classes.

Also note that this query can potentially return a large amount of data, so you should be careful with your projection.